How to make your Discord bot add a string of text to it's previous message?
I need my Discord bot to edit their own previous message, adding a string of text. But I don't understand how to accomplish this. I am using discord.py.
My Discord bot is for hosting reservations for a grand-strategy video game. The bot sends the contents of a .txt file into a channel via message, which contains a list of playable nations. Then a user can do '!reserve (x nation)', and the bot proceeds to update it's list to add that user's name to the list, next to their chosen (x nation).
However, I don't understand how to make the bot edit, and then add strings of text to a message it has previously sent. I have looked through discord.py documentation and browsed stackoverflow, but haven't found anything that has addressed this issue. Additionally, I would need to program the bot to put the user's name after the user's chosen 'nation', inside the list.
For example:
bot message:
Playable Nations List
USA
Italy
...
upon command '!reserve USA'
bot message  (edited):
Playable Nations List
USA @user
Italy
...
Regarding code; I have set up a function to grab the message ID of the bot's original message. It is simply the process after that which is incomprehensible to me.
Here is the code:
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The bot is now ready")
    try:
        synced = await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=GUILD_ID))
        print(f"Synced {len(synced)} command(s)")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

@client.command()
async def host(ctx):
    with open('host-template.txt', 'r') as fp:
        message = await ctx.send(fp.read())
    with open('message.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(message.id))

@client.command()
async def reserve_USA(ctx):
    channel = client.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    with open("message.txt", "r") as f:
        message_id = int(f.read())
    message = await channel.fetch_message(message_id)
    await message.edit(content="CONTENT") #This basic message.edit function is not feasible.



client.run(BOTTOKEN)

Here is the contents of 'host-template.txt':
Available Nations

USA
Japan
UK
USSR
Germany
France
Italy


I'm not but when you keep object message in global variable then you can use it to edit this message later. But bot keep connection with different users at the same time then it may need to keep it as dictionary {user.id: message} to get correct message for correct user.

I think you are better off using embeds for this. Embeds have fields, which can be easily manipulated. For every country, you can add a field and then add a person under that field. Besides, it will also look way more appealing to the eye.
For starters, you'll have to remove the Available Nations from host-template.txt and make it only the countries. Then, you can .readlines() on it, which will return a list with every line.
with open("host-template.txt") as f:
    countries = f.readlines() # countries will now be ['USA', 'Japan', ...] 

You need to keep the countries in separate lines for this to work.
And then, you can use discord.Embed and construct an embed and then add a new field for every country. For example:
country_embed = discord.Embed(title="Available Nations")
for country in countries:
   country_embed.add_field(name=country, value="N/A") # we can edit the N/A later with our list of members

.send() has an embed kwarg and to send the embed, we will pass our embed instance there.
await ctx.send(embed=country_embed)

Then, when you edit it, you can fetch the message and access message.embeds which is a list. Since there's only one embed in the message, we get that embed by indexing 0.
message = await channel.fetch_message(message_id)
country_embed = message.embeds[0]

Now, we get the field we need to edit. Message.embeds is a list so we'll use indexing to get the field we want. The fields will be created in the order the countries are in host-template.txt, so if we want to access Japan which is second, we'll subtract 1 from it since indexing starts at 0 and not 1. So,
2 - 1 = 1.
japan_field = country_embed.fields[1]
# Now, we will remove the field and add it again using `Embed.insert_field_at`.
country_embed.remove_field(1)
# We need to check if the value is "N/A" (no users) or if there are users
new_value = ""
if japan_field.value == "N/A": # There is no user so we can replace it
    new_value = "<your_new_value>"
else: # There are users logged, so we add to it
    new_value = f"{japan_field.value}\n" + "<your_new_value>"
# Now, we insert the field at the same index
country_embed.insert_field_at(1, name=japan_field.name, value=new_value)
# And now, edit the message with the new embed
await message.edit(embed=country_embed)

This can be hard to follow, if you have any doubts you can comment below.
References:

insert_field_at: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Embed.insert_field_at
message.embeds: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.embeds
embed.fields: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Embed.fields


Hey! Thanks for the answer - helps out a lot! However, the 'e.remove_field(1)' line of code is all undefined. Not sure how to fix it, even after looking at documentation.
Edit: Fixed it by writing 'country_embed.remove_field(1)'

yeah i accidentally put e there, mb
